# how can i make a default answer in a text game when the user types in a wrong input?

Tags: objective-c, c

this is my code so far, i am using objective c. It is small, but i would like to make a default answer, for example if someone types in "i like pie" it will say "i don't understand".

```
    printf("This is a text game! You will be shown what is going on");
    printf("\nand it is up to you to decide what to do.");

    printf("\n\nThere is a gem on the ground.");
    printf("\nWhat do you want to do");
    printf("\n>");

    char string[256];
    fgets(string, 255, stdin);

    if (strcmp(string, "pick up gem\n") == 0)
    {
        printf("Got Gem");
    }
    else if (strcmp(string, "kick gem\n") == 0){
        printf("Gem flew off the road.");
    }
```

Comment: Note that everything in the code you've posted is regular C, not Objective-C. There's nothing wrong with that, because all valid C is also valid Objective-C, but it's not the way an Objective-C program is typically written.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen can you mark my post up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might write:

```
if (strcmp(string, "pick up gem\n") == 0)
    {
        printf("Got Gem");
    }
    else if (strcmp(string, "kick gem\n") == 0){
        printf("Gem flew off the road.");
    }
else {
    printf("What?");
}
```

"What?", then, would be your default answer.

Comment: You're welcome. You're getting the right idea with regard to questions.

Comment: I finally got how to ask questions, i noticed you said my questions weren't questions.

Comment: That's because your previous questions would have taken volumes to answer because they were so broad. You're beginning to understand, I can tell, how SO works.

Comment: @codegeek511 You just learned something else! It's always a good day when you learn stuff.

Comment: This is a very general answer, but at the very least, you should think of additional functions that handle each of your traveler's obstacles. Create a new one, for example, for the troll. This issue, however, might best be discussed in a new question.

Comment: Due to my other posts, i cant post any more questions. I feel this is unfair because i had no idea, but know i now what to ask, i fixed my posts, but can you mark it back up?

Comment: Hey, can you also show me how to link two situations together. I can get one scenario, but how do i make it jump to another separate if statement.

Comment: @codegeek511 Post that issue as a question. Your inability to post questions (referring to your earlier comment) shouldn't be permanent; do try again. If you still can't, then try waiting until 24 hours have passed (15 as of now). If that doesn't work, then contact a moderator; they may be able to help you.

Comment: I will try again, but i emailed the support team and they just referred me to the help section on the subject, witch i read and i changed my posts accordingly. But i will keep trying.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
if (strcmp(string, "pick up gem\n") == 0){
    printf("Got Gem");
}
else if (strcmp(string, "kick gem\n") == 0){
    printf("Gem flew off the road.");
}   
else{
    printf("I don't understand.");
}
```

Then, for anything other than your two expected inputs, it will print *"I don't understand"*.